# Is "on camping" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

For example, if I wanted to describe something that had just happened *but* also happened to me on a recent camping trip. Would it be grammatically correct to say, "that happened to me on camping too"?

Comment: The same thing happened to me *out camping.*

Comment: No. Idiomatic are ('while' often being understood): 'that happened to us on vacation' / 'on our honeymoon' /  'on summer break' / 'on holiday' /  'on safari' / 'on trek' ( / 'on duty').

Comment: No = "that happened to me **when** camping, too".

Answer (score 1):

I would use "while camping" here, e.g. "that happened to me while camping too".

Sometimes people will say something happened "on camp", or "at camp". To take an slightly dated pop culture example, one of the characters in the movie *American Pie* often tells anecdotes that start "this one time, at band camp, ...".

Comment: Or "when camping".  But not "on camping".

Comment: To be clear, “at camp” is different to “while camping”.  “At camp” means while away at a camp like a summer camp, band camp, sea camp, etc.  whereas “camping” just means out in the wilderness typically with a sleeping bag and  tent- although some people extend that to include trailers and RVs.